# Different browser behaviors on <select> tag

Tags: html, css, safari, html-select

### Question

I want to eliminate the sliding animation when a select menu option is chosen.

---

### Background

All of these are recorded on OS X Yosemite:

- [Chrome](http://cl.ly/image/030F021r282M?_ga=1.221780312.1158057015.1435556733) (no sliding animation on selecting an option)
- [Safari](http://cl.ly/image/3F2j3D2B1c1o?_ga=1.220615256.1158057015.1435556733) (has sliding animation on selecting an option)
- [Firefox](http://cl.ly/image/372f0S2U3F3U?_ga=1.221780312.1158057015.1435556733) (entirely different style and behavior)

What is causing the differing browser behavior (style, selection animation) when a select menu option is chosen?

It doesn't appear to be the user agent stylesheet of the browser—I tried overriding Safari's user agent stylesheet by using Chrome's default user agent stylesheet from the [Chromium source](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/css/html.css&q=type=%22search%22&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=430), but this did not change Safari's behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is these browser are of different vendor and they implement every element differently and `CSS` as well you need to add CSS vender prefix to apply CSS Style sheet. But not every browser support all CSS property. You can get list of supported property from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp).
That's why every browser show different behavior.

Comment: I'd just add you can see how different browsers handle selects and other inputs using this tool: http://inputtypes.com/